# Rendered fewer hooks than expected error in the return statement

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to build a simple navbar but when I define a setResponsivness function inside my useEffect
I am getting the error *Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.* I looked at similar answers for the same but till wasn't able to fix

Here s my code

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import {AppBar ,Toolbar, Container ,makeStyles,Button, IconButton} from '@material-ui/core'
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'

const usestyles = makeStyles({
    root:{
       
        display:'flex',
        justifyContent:'space-between' ,
        maxWidth:'700px'
    },
   menubtn:{
    fontFamily: "Work Sans, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 500,
    paddingRight:'79px',
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "left",
    },
    menuicon:{
      edge: "start",color: "inherit",paddingLeft:'0'
    }
})

const menudata = [
    {
      label: "home",
      href: "/",
    },
    {
      label: "About",
      href: "/about",
    },
    {
      label: "Skill",
      href: "/skills",
    },
    {
      label: "Projects",
      href: "/projects",
    },
    {
      label: "Contact",
      href: "/contact",
    },
  ];

//yet to target link for the smooth scroll
function getmenubuttons(){
    const {menubtn} = usestyles();
    return menudata.map(({label,href})=>{
        return <Button className={menubtn}>{label}</Button>
    })
} 
//to display navbar on desktop screen
function displaydesktop(){
    const { root } = usestyles() //destructuring our custom defined css classes
    return <Toolbar ><Container maxWidth={false} className={root}>{getmenubuttons()}</Container>   </Toolbar>
}
//to display navbar on mobile screen
function displaymobile(){
  const {menuicon} =usestyles() ;
  return <Toolbar><IconButton className={menuicon}><MenuIcon />  </IconButton></Toolbar>
}
function Navbar() {
     const [state, setState] = useState({mobileview:false});
     const {mobileview} = state;

     useEffect(() => {
      const setResponsiveness = () => {
        return window.innerWidth < 900
          ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileview: true }))
          : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileview: false }));
      };
  
      setResponsiveness();
  
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
          <AppBar> {mobileview?displaymobile():displaydesktop()} </AppBar>        
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here

```
{mobileview?displaymobile():displaydesktop()}
```

For example the `displaymobile` function inside uses hooks right (`usestyles`)? Then it means you are rendering hooks inside conditions (`mobileview` being condition) which is not allowed by rules of hooks.

You can fix it like this:

```
    <div>
      <AppBar> {mobileview ? <Displaymobile /> : <Displaydesktop />} </AppBar>
    </div>
```

Also change definition of component using capital letters as that is how react refers to components. e.g.

```
function Displaydesktop() {
  const { root } = usestyles(); //destructuring our custom defined css classes
  return (
    <Toolbar>
      <Container maxWidth={false} className={root}>
        {getmenubuttons()}
      </Container>{" "}
    </Toolbar>
  );
}
```

Now we consume them as components. Probably when you used lower case letters and called those as functions in your render, react interpreted them as custom hooks, hence the warnings.